The code for calculating vegetation indices in GEE
I want to write a code to calculate the  vegetation indices in GEE so that there are no clouds on the field polygon
But this filter, filters the entire image collection, not just the polygon!
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var land = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
;

var Indices = function(img){
 var NDVI = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5','SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')
 var GNDVI = img.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5','SR_B3']).rename('GNDVI')
 var EVI = img.expression('2.5* ((B5-B4) / (B5 + 6 * B4 - 7.5 * B2 + 1))',{
    'B5': img.select('SR_B5'),
    'B4': img.select('SR_B4'),
    'B2': img.select('SR_B2'),
  }).rename('EVI')
  var SAVI = img.expression('((B5 - B4) / (B5 + B4 + 0.5)) * (1.5)',{
    'B5': img.select('SR_B5'),
    'B4': img.select('SR_B4')
  }).rename('SAVI')
  var RVI = img.expression('(B4 / B5)',{
    'B5': img.select('SR_B5'),
    'B4': img.select('SR_B4')
  }).rename('RVI')
  var OSAVI = img.expression('((1+0.16)*(B5-B4))/(B5+B4+0.16)',{
    'B5': img.select('SR_B5'),
    'B4': img.select('SR_B4')
  }).rename('OSAVI')
  return img.addBands(NDVI).addBands(EVI).addBands(SAVI).addBands(GNDVI).addBands(RVI).addBands(OSAVI)
}

var image = land
.filterBounds(table)
.filterDate('2018-09-01','2019-09-01')
.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER',10))
.map(Indices)
print(image);


var chart = ui.Chart.image.series(
  image.select(['NDVI','EVI','SAVI','GNDVI','RVI','OSAVI']),table, ee.Reducer.mean(),30,'system:time_start'
  );
  print (chart);



With land.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER',10)), you are indeed are filtering out complete images from your image collection based on their overall cloud cover percentage.
I assume you are asking how to mask individual cloudy pixels. You have the QA_PIXEL band containing the information for doing this. Below you have one approach for using it. You can find the bitmask for QA_PIXEL in the EE data catalog. bitwiseExtract() is a little utility function I've created for extracting the values in a simple way, without having to think about the bit-fiddling details every time. updateMask() will perform the actual masking, in this example, keeping ony pixels which are not cloud shadow, cloud, or snow (clouds are sometimes misclassified as snow).
var maskClouds = function(img) {
  var qa = img.select('QA_PIXEL')
  var cloudShadow = bitwiseExtract(qa, 4)
  var snow = bitwiseExtract(qa, 5).rename('snow')
  var cloud = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6).not().rename('cloud')
  return img.updateMask(
    cloudShadow.not()
      .and(cloud.not())
      .and(snow.not())
  )
}

var bitwiseExtract = function(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined) {
    toBit = fromBit
  }
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}

Another important step you have to do before using data in collection 2 Landsat collections, is to apply the correct scale factors. The EE data catalog also describes how to do that:
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0)
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true)
}

Below is how to put it together. Note that you might still want to filter the collection by CLOUD_COVER, picking an appropriate threshold based on your area.
var image = land
  .filterBounds(table)
  .filterDate('2018-09-01', '2019-09-01')
  // .filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('CLOUD_COVER', 10))
  .map(applyScaleFactors)
  .map(maskClouds)
  .map(Indices)

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5574e5386993e5506b4302e75a8c284f
